HyperV Error: "The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag."
I have a virtual machine within Windows 10 HyperV which was previously working fine. But today it will no longer start up.
I happened to move the location of the ISO assigned to the virtual DVD drive, which gave me an initial error, but after I fixed that by updating its location in settings, I now get a different error:

'[Virtual Machine Name]' failed to restore.
Microsoft Virtual TPM Device (Instance ID ...): Failed to restore with Error:
'The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag.'


Has anyone else come across this error and found a fix?

Remove the vTPM. Here is an explanation of what’s happening. Doing this will of course effect BitLocker on the VM

@Ramhound Yes, I thought that might be a solution, however that cannot be done while the machine is in a saved state. Most (if not all) of my checkpoints are in a saved (powered on) state, so it might be tricky to do that. Unless I create a completely new machine but reuse the virtual disk? That might be an option. But I've found a workaround for the time being - will post an answer below.

Your screenshot shows that the VM is saved. You can try to delete the saved state and then restart the machine.

Does deleting the saved state just erase the RAM? Or will it also lose hard drive data, going all the way back to the most recent checkpoint?

Some potential workarounds I've discovered so far:

Disable the "Trusted Platform Module (TPM)"  (as suggested by @Ramhound)
Under Instance Settings > Security
However I wasn't able to do this while the machine is in a saved state. I would likely need to find a way to shut off the machine, potentially losing any data in RAM, and then disable TPM.
This would also likely prevent Bitlocker-encrypted drives from being readable.

Move the ISO that is assigned to the virtual DVD drive back to its original location.
Having this in a different folder appears to invalidate the TPM for some reason. Once I moved the ISO back, the machine booted with no error.



Select the VM in HyperV... right column... "delete saved state".
Takes a moment and with a "sucess", it starts again.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This answer, merged with Situ's answer above will be a complete answer. On their own, both are mostly just comments.
